# Howto change windows 8 tile based on an image from local storage

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro

I'm writing an windows 8 app which should change the tile based on images from local storage.

First, i store an image from an url into local storage:

```
         const string fileName = "test.jpg";
        StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        using (IRandomAccessStream storageStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            Stream imageStream = await client.GetStreamAsync("http://suntsu.smugmug.com/Public/NikonTest/i-5L8JLTz/0/Th/20120124_Nikon_Macro_2-Th.jpg");

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                imageStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            }
            await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(imageStream.AsInputStream(), destination: storageStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
        }
```

This works, and i can access the file via:

```
  //var file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri( "ms-appdata:///local/" + fileName));
```

Now i want to add this image as my new live:

```
            XmlDocument tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideImageAndText01);
        XmlNodeList tileTextElements = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        tileTextElements.Item(0).AppendChild(tileXml.CreateTextNode(fileName));
        XmlNodeList tileImageAttributes = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
        tileImageAttributes[0].Attributes[1].NodeValue = "ms-appdata:///local/" + fileName;
```

The problem now is that nothing happens, and no image is shown in my tile.

I guess the problem is related to **"ms-appdata:///local/" + fileName;**, because if i use the code for loading the file from my app folder, it works. **"ms-appx:///images/graySquare.png";**

Question:
Is **"ms-appdata:///local/" + fileName;** wrong in order to set the link to a image from local storage? And how must it be done?

EDIT: I forgott to add the the code which should add the newly created tiles.

```
                ScheduledTileNotification tileNotification = new ScheduledTileNotification(tileXml, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(count));
            TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);
            TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().AddToSchedule(tileNotification);
```

Edit: 
Is there a possibilty to validate **"ms-appdata:///local/myimage.jpg"** in order to make sure this uri is correct, and the image exists?

Comment: You only changed the XmlDocument, you didn't do anything with it.  There's sample code in the TileNotification class article on MSDN.

Comment: I forgot to add this code. But it is there and as i wrote, the tile works if i set the image from ms-appx, but not if it is set from ms-appdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. 
The problem was not the path. **"ms-appdata:///local/myimage.jpg"** was correct. 
The code for writing the files is not correct, and so there only were 0 byte images. 
This did not cause any exceptions or messages, but the tile was not updated.